# check if in existing result set all days within month are present

Tags: mysql, date

How can I check if in my result set (which is formed by query shown below at the end) for every month exists every day? For example in below result set:

```
Date_List
08/01/2016
08/02/2016
08/03/2016
08/04/2016
08/05/2016
08/06/2016
08/07/2016
08/08/2016
08/09/2016
08/10/2016
08/11/2016
08/12/2016
08/13/2016
08/14/2016
08/15/2016
08/16/2016
08/17/2016
08/18/2016
08/19/2016
08/20/2016
08/21/2016
08/22/2016
08/23/2016
08/24/2016
08/25/2016
08/26/2016
08/27/2016
08/28/2016
08/29/2016
08/30/2016
08/31/2016
```

We can see that August 2016 has all days available. I want to return only such months (with all days available) with a year part of course. In this case it would be 08/16 (MM/YYYY) to return. Thus if any day for any month is missing - I do not want to return such month.

Here is the query I use to form result set:

```
SELECT d.`Date_List` FROM staging_area.`g360_dates_ca` d
LEFT JOIN dm_research_development.g360_pro_saas_availability a
ON d.`Date_List` = a.`DATE_OCCURRED_DATE` AND a.`IS_OUTAGE` = 'YES'
WHERE a.`DATE_OCCURRED_DATE` IS NULL AND STR_TO_DATE(d.`Date_List`,'%m/%d/%Y') <= NOW();
```

g360_dates_ca table contains all dates starting 01-01-2013 till 01-01-2018.

g360_pro_saas_availability - is my incidents table with details.

Comment: count them, and compare that against how many days that month should have. And note that your SHOULD redo your database to store those as ACTUAL dates. Since they're not dates, they're strings/varchars, you can't index them, and have to dynamically convert them to dates every single time, which means performance will be totally crappy.

Comment: thanks for the answer, could you please list down the query for count that you proposed?